# Get Sub Image dynamically using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ocr

I want to extract a specific portion of an image for my project.
Since, the images I will be getting are scanned documents, that specific part maybe shifted a little bit so, I can't write hard coded value
[image: Here is the image]

I want to take out text from that image, but I can manage that only if I get that portion marked in red

Comment: I have used Contours with canny edge detection but couldn't get the result properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dilation and make contour. Just tweak parameters for various function to get the desired output.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('pan2.jpg')
img1 =  cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
f1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
f1 = 255 - cv2.threshold(f1, 0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
fgdilated = cv2.dilate(f1, kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3)) , iterations = 1)
fgclosing = cv2.morphologyEx(fgdilated, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2,2)))

plt.imshow(fgclosing)
plt.show()
img2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgdilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for cnt in contours:
    #print(cnt)
    #print(cv2.contourArea(cnt))
    if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 200:
        #hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
        #print(hull)
        #cv2.drawContours(img, [hull], -1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if h >7:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255, 0, 255), 1)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

**Input:**

[image: Input]

This is the Binary image i get using the code.

[image: Binary Image]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Apply `GaussianBlur` to your image first, e. g. with a kernel size of 3.

After finding the edges with proper values using `Canny` (since the conditions under which you take the images [scanning] do not differ much, you should be able to find such values for min/max in canny) you can find Edge points using `findContours`
fit an Rectangle using `minAreaRect`. Crop this part of the image then.

Comment: yeah I tried that but it seems to be a little lengthy way of doing and since i want it dynamic, it is not working for some cases